# Introducing custom line spacing between chapter number and the title

Tags: spacing, sectioning, lyx, chapters

The university requires that the following conditions be met for the thesis. I use sectsy package to get the required font size and am using standard report class. How to get the proper spacing between the top margin and chapter number and chapter number and chapter title?

[image]

Comment: Package `titlesec` can be of help here. `\titleformat` and `\titlespacing` are the commands to read about.

Answer (score 2):

As Johannes_B writes: Use the package [titlesec](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) instead of `sectsty` because `titlesec` has more advanced features, including the ability to define custom spacing between the elements of a chapter.

You use the command

```
\titlespacing*{command}{left}{before-sep}{after-sep}[right-sep]
```

To define the spacing, see section 3.2, page 4 in the manual. For you, the correct values may be:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\filcenter\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}
    {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{25mm}{\LARGE}  %% \LARGE gives 17.28 pt if main
                                                    %% font size is 10 or 11 pt, which
                                                    %% should be close enough
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0mm}{75mm}{25mm}
```

The space between chapter number and the chapter text is defined by the 25 mm command in the `\chapterformat`. The space before and after the chapter by the `\titlespacing`. See section 9.2 in the manual to see the definition of all section commands in the standard class. You can then just redefine those to get the result you desire.

You will learn more if you read the manual and experiment and come back and ask more questions (if you search for titlesec, you will probably find most problem already solved).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but am working with Lyx and when I enter the above mentioned commands in the preamble, it gives me the following error.                                                                   ! Package titlesec Error: Not allowed in `easy' settings.                   ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

Comment: @Curious I do not know Lyx, but I am pretty sure it is possible to enter LaTeX-code in the preamble. Maybe some LyX-experts may help you.

Comment: @Curious Looking into your error message, it seems that you have chosen one of the `easy`-options described in section 2.1 in the manual. Try loading `titlesec` without any options and see if it works better.

Comment: I didn't specify any option. I just copy paste the code written above to see whether it works or nor.

Comment: @Curious Did you remember to load `titlesec`in you preamble? I do not have LyX installed, and cannot test myself.

Comment: I did add \usepackage {titlesec} and then only added the above code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50337/discussion-between-curious-and-sveinung).

Comment: @Curious I rechecked my code, and it was errors in it. See updated example.

Comment: Thanks for the update. When I add the code in the preamble, it gives me an error saying that "can't use \eqno in math mode". This is happening only in the case of a numbered formula. Does not happen when the same formula is inline. This is strange. If I removed the titlesec code, then everything works fine.

Comment: @Curious My only guess is that titlesec interfere with another package in you setup. I have no idea why you get such strange error message.

Comment: @Curious Do you have a equation in the chapter title?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I solved it. The text was defined as a paragraph instead of standard.